# how to use X509 certificates (to sign a file w/ simple verification, + other questions)

Tags: cryptography, openssl, x509

I spent several hours yesterday trying to digitally sign a short file using an X509 certificate (one of the "freemail" certificates from thawte). I finally got openssl to sign it as an SMIME message, but I can't successfully verify it, AND it's in the SMIME format -- I don't have access to a "sendmail" program which can actually send out the SMIME file.

I just want to create some file that is "excerptable" via plain cut & paste, like:

```
===BEGIN SIGNED DOCUMENT===
===BEGIN DOCUMENT===
blah blah blah this is the plaintext ...
===END DOCUMENT===
===BEGIN SIGNATURE===
AFab12121abadAF ...
===END SIGNATURE===
===END SIGNED DOCUMENT===
```

Alternatively I guess I could make a .zip file that contains the original file and also the signature.

so I guess my requirements are:

1. input plaintext = arbitrary file
2. input signkey = from X509 certificate
3. output = something I can easily email to someone else by cut&paste or by attaching a single .zip file
4. program = something that is free & open source like openssl or gpg
5. program != a magic GUI where I don't understand what's going on
6. ability to easily use the program to generate output from inputs
7. ability to easily extract the plaintext from the output (e.g. either directly by eye or as a component of the .zip file)
8. ability to verify that the plaintext was signed by the grantee of the X509 certificate (i.e. me) and that the grantor (CA) of the certificate is a Well-Known CA... assuming that I am a rational person who keeps the certificate secure from use by other parties (otherwise someone could sign things as me).

Is there a good tutorial for X509 certificates & how they are used in practice for this stuff? I have the 2nd edition of Schneier's "Applied Cryptography" & have a fair amount of experience with cryptographic algorithms + protocols, but don't know much at all about X509 and I'm really confused as to what a certificate actually is in practical terms. (In other words, "a certificate is a cryptographic assertion by the issuing party CA that the party X named in the certificate is an identity known to the CA?" AND "a certificate enables its bearer to _____")

When I get one it shows up in Firefox's "Your Certificates" tab of the Certificate Manager, and I can export it and read it with openssl, but I want to make sure that it's not stored in any way that someone else can use it w/o knowing the cert. passphrase -- and I get really confused because it seems like some certificates only have the public key & others have encrypted private keys.

Is there a good, simple GUI wrapper around openssl that allows you to have it explain what it's doing?

---

**edit:** thawte doesn't easily let you use certificate requests directly; instead it talks to web browsers (I use Firefox) & that generatese the private key and handles all the certificate protocol. So I can export that as a PKCS12 file but am not exactly sure how to use that.

Answer (score 2):

> So I can export that as a PKCS12 file but am not exactly sure how to use that.

If you use the openssl tool, you can use the command

```
openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12 -out file.pem
```

to convert it to pem-format.

**EDIT**:

> I'm having trouble figuring out what PEM and PKCS12 and all these things do differently from each other

A PKCS#12 file is just a container for certificates and keys. If you want to see what it contains (at least except for the encrypted parts), you can use a tool such as [dumpasn1](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/dumpasn1.c). The PKCS#12 file that you export from your browser will contain your private key in an encrypted format, your certificate as well as the CA certificates that are necessary to form a chain up to a trusted CA.

Likewise a PEM file can contain certificates and keys. In a PEM file the certificates and keys are base64 encoded and placed within some text delimiters (a PKCS#12 file uses a binary encoding named ASN.1 to structure the file - you can think of ASN.1 as a binary form of XML. Most cryptographic structures you encounter will have been encoded using ASN.1). Except for that, the only real difference between the formats is that PKCS#12 contains an integrity check - otherwise the formats are equivalent.

OpenSSL works best with PEM, while most browsers and emailapplications will expect PKCS#12, but you can freely convert between the formats.

Comment: I figured that out, but I'm having trouble figuring out what PEM and PKCS12 and all these things do differently from each other. It's like putting plumbing together in loopy circles & knots. I can figure out how to make the individual connections but the big picture is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

First you probably need to read up on the difference between a private key, a public key and a certificate. A certificate is a signature with a CAs private key on the statement "The public key XX belongs to the person YY". If you sign something with your private key, the signature can be validated with your public key, and a third party that trusts the CA can conclude that the signature was signed by you.

If you generate a S/MIME message and attach it as a file with the extension .p7s, most mail programs will probably be able to verify it.

If you want total control over what you are doing, my experience is that the tooling around the PGP-format gives you better control (compared to the mail-programs implementing the S/MIME protocol).